# Mock static method from external Class (that I can't change!)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I want to mock (with gmock) a static function from a class that I can't change.
A is the class that I want to mock:

```
Class A
{
public:
   static std::string get_id();
...
}
```

B is my class that I want to test with gmock:

```
Class B
{
public:
   B(A *a_ptr);
   ...

   std::string foo();
private:
   A *m_a_ptr;
}

B::B(A *a_ptr) : m_a_ptr(a_ptr)
{
}

std::string B::foo()
{
   id = m_a_ptr->get_id();
   return id;
}
```

How can I mock the method get_id without changing the class A?

Comment: If the function is static, why do you call it with the pointer to A? If you change the static call, it would be easier to mock it or am i wrong? Or are you not allowed to change B too?

Comment: so I just use A::get_id()? Then I mock foo() for when I have to use it in other parts of my class? That actually would work since the only think that foo does is calling get_id(). Thanks!

Comment: As bad as it sounds, but I am not familiar how to mock correctly in such cases, but I would guess, yes. B::foo should something be called B::GetIDOfA or something and this could be mocked

Comment: @RoQuOTriX you can mock static methods in GMock by delegation, which works quite fine along with statically injecting production intent type vs mocked type in the (class templated) type that make use of the type to be mocked (see my answer below for details).

Answer (score 4):

#### Static dependency injection and GMock delegation

We will start by minimizing your example to the following (to keep the passages that follows as non-noisy as possible):

```
// a.h
#include <string>

// class to mock
class A {
    static std::string get_id();
};

// b.h
#include <string>
#include "a.h"

// class that use A
struct B {
    std::string foo() const {
        return A::get_id();
    }
};
```

Although you cannot change `A`, you can change `B` to *statically inject* `A` in product code, whereas you can statically inject a mock delegate of `A` for test code:

```
// b.h
#include <string>
#include "a.h"

namespace detail {
// The type template parameter is set to A by default, 
// and should not need to override this default type 
// in production code, but can be injected with 
// mocked classes in test code.
template<typename AImpl = ::A>
struct BImpl {
   std::string foo() const {
        return A::get_id();
   }
};
}  // namespace detail

// Expose product-intent specialization.
using B = BImpl<>;
```

Where the mock for `A` make use of static (non-thread safe) approach to mock calls to the injected static type:

```
// a_mock.h
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class AMock {
    // Mocked methods.
    struct Mock {
        MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(get_id,
                           std::string());
    };

    // Stubbed public API for static function of object under test:
    // delegates stubbed calls to the mock.
    static std::string get_id() {
        if (const auto mock = mock_.lock()) {
            mock->get_id();
        }
        else {
            ADD_FAILURE() 
                << "Invalid mock object! The test can no "
                   "longer be considered useful!";   
        }
    }

    // Public setter to specify the mock instance used in test (which in
    // turn will be the instance that Google Test's EXPECTS and mocked
    // calls is placed upon).
    static void setMock(const std::shared_ptr<Mock>& mock) { mock_ = mock; }

  private:
    // Pointer to mock instance.
    static std::weak_ptr<Mock> mock_;
};
```

which can, finally, be used in tests of `BImpl` as follows:

```
// b_test.cpp
#include "b.h"  // object under test
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "a_mock.h"

class BImplTest : public ::testing::Test {
public:
    using BImplUnderTest = BImpl<AMock>;

    BImplTest() : amock_(std::make_shared<AMock::Mock>()) {
        AMock::setMock(amock_);
    }
};

TEST_F(BImplTest, foo) {
    // Setup mocked call(s).
    EXPECT_CALL(amock_, foo()).WillOnce(::testing::Return( /*...*/ ));

    // Call object under test.
    BImplUnderTest b{};
    b.foo();
      
}
```

---

#### Further hiding the fact that `B` is in fact a specialization of a class template `BImpl`

If you start to heavily use this pattern (in a sliding-window manner over different sub-routines) and want to avoid single large and bloated translation units, you could move the definitions of the member functions of the `detail::B` class template to separate header, say `b-timpl.h` (which includes `b.h`) and in the source file associated with `b.h`, say `b.cpp`, include `b-timpl.h` instead of `b.h` and add an explicit instantiation definition for the production intent `detail::BImpl` specialization:

```
// b.cpp
template class ::detail::BImpl<>;
```

Whereas in tests of `::detail::BImpl` you include `b-timpl.h` instead of `b.h` and add an explicit instantiation definition for the mock-injected specialization of the class template:

```
// b_test.cpp
#include "b-timpl.h"
// ...

template class ::detail::BImpl<AMock>;

// ...
```

Why? The `BImpl` class is not parameterized to allow a user of its interface to statically inject different behahaviour (for user intent, users should only see `B`), but to allow injecting mocked or stubbed classes while testing.

Comment: Thanks, but that makes the code really complicate, or?

Comment: @dfrib I think your `BImpl` implementation might have a bug. Shouldn't it `return AImpl::get_id();` instead of `return A::get_id();`?